# For doorkeeper gem, why do we need to set redirect_url at both server dashboard and request param from client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I'm looking at some examples about doorkeeper gem. One thing I noticed is they set redirect url at 2 places. One is when they create a new oauth application at /oauth/applications, the other is when client makes a request to /oauth/authorize to get access code. I'm wondering why they need to set redirect url at 2 places?

Answer (score 1):

It is not just doorkeeper's implementation. It is indeed defined by Oauth2 documentation. You can see that redirect_uri is defined as parameter of two endpoint at here:

- [One is when they create a new oauth application at /oauth/applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) - 4.1.1.  Authorization Request
- [the other is when client makes a request to /oauth/authorize to get access code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) - 4.1.3. Access Token Request

"Why they need to set redirect url at 2 places?" Because:

- client can register multiple redirect_uri on Authorization server. [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2): "provide its **client redirection URIs** as described in Section 3.1.2"
- After client send one of registered redirect_uri at Authorization Request (4.1.1) to AuthorizationServer, *client will received authorization_code in response from AuthorizationServer to redirect_uri*. So when you exchange that authorization_code for access_token at AccessToken Request (4.1.3), you need to send the same redirect_uri to make Authorization Server makes sure that requested authorization_code is binding with redirect_uri.